# VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native

I get the error **VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews** when I open my DropDown and cannot select or scroll the DrowDown dialog, I know approximately what the problem is, could someone please tell me the reason or show me the solution?

```js
<ScrollView>
  {formSchema.map((field, index) => {
    const { name, label, type } = field;
    if (type === 'select') {
      return (
        <View style={styles.sropsownWrapper} key={index}>
          <Dropdown
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
    if (type === 'input') {
      return (
        <View style={styles.wrapper}>
          <Input
            name={name}
            label={label}
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
  })}
  <View
    style={{
      ...styles.controls,
      backgroundColor: '#242424',
    }}>
    <View style={styles.wrapper}>
      <Button onPress={() => ()} />
    </View>
    <View style={styles.wrapper}>
      <Button  text="Go" />
    </View>
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: What version of https://github.com/hossein-zare/react-native-dropdown-picker do you have installed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](https://hossein-zare.github.io/react-native-dropdown-picker-website/docs/advanced/list-modes/#notes) suggests adding `listMode="MODAL"` or `listMode="SCROLLVIEW"` to avoid the issue.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use FlatList instead ScrollView as container:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist

```
<FlatList
 data={formSchema}
 rederItem={(field, index) => {
  const { name, label, type } = field;
  if (type === 'select') {
    return (
      <View style={styles.sropsownWrapper} key={index}>
        <Dropdown
          name={name}
          label={label}
          list={field.list}
          placeholder={`Select please ${label}`}
          handleSelect={(value) => setFieldValue(name, value)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
  if (type === 'input') {
    return (
      <View style={styles.wrapper}>
        <Input
          name={name}
          label={label}
          placeholder={`Enter Data ${label}`}
          onChangeText={handleChange(name)}
          onBlur={(name) => setFieldTouched(name)}
          value={values[name]}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
 }
}
[...]
```

If it still complains, you can use the properties ListHeaderComponent and ListFooterComponent for a definitive solution.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#listheadercomponent

(Also you could add `nestedScrollEnabled={true}` to ScrollView but it only works on Android)

Answer (score -1):

This happens due to Nesting of `<ScrollView />` in the same orientation.

In your case `<ScrollView />` and `<Dropdown />` have the same scroll direction. you can check this for more information. https://github.com/hossein-zare/react-native-dropdown-picker/issues/56

you can use this to ignore this warning.

```
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';

useEffect(() => {
    YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['VirtualizedLists should never be nested']);
}, [])
```